# Erro ao tentar instalar scikit-learn

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Eu estou tentando instalar o scikit-learn via pip para python 3.9, mas na parte que diz "Installing build dependencies..." ocorre um erro toda vez. Eu já instalei o numpy e o scipy, que são pré-requisitos, e até já formatei meu PC, mas ainda dá o erro. A mensagem de erro é muito grande, mas essas são as linhas iniciais e finais, que eu acredito que são as mais importantes:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\alfredo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\alfredo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rs86gbfh\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None

.
.
.

----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\alfredo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alfredo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wn_2dnvm\\numpy_32582bf8a3d04f8fa43ffe9d540c089c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alfredo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wn_2dnvm\\numpy_32582bf8a3d04f8fa43ffe9d540c089c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_e01fgoh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rs86gbfh\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rs86gbfh\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\alfredo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\alfredo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-rs86gbfh\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Embora o sckit-learn mostre que funciona na versão 3.6 ou superior do Python. Acredito que é até a 3.8...

Comment: @PauloMarques era isso mesmo. Desinstalei o Python 3.9 e instalei o 3.8 e funcionou. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta atualizar o setuptools

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Se não der certo manda o erro completo se tiver mais ai.

Comment: Fiz isso mas ainda dá o erro. A mensagem de erro é grande demais e excede a limitação de caracteres...

Answer (score -1):

Prezado,

Estou presumindo que vc esta usando o Windows, primeiro tenta
atualizar o pip, sempre usando o CMD no modo administrador:

```
pip install -U pip --user
```

Depois da instalação:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn --user
```

Acredito que assim deve funcionar, espero ter ajudado e qualquer
dúvida estamos por aqui